# std::visit does not accept a callable that is a derived class object

Tags: c++, c++17, std, variant

I am trying to use `std::visit` to inspect an `std::variant`.
First I declare the variant and a base (callable) visitor class for the variant:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>


using Amalgamation = std::variant<int, bool, std::string>;

class BaseVisitor {
public:
    virtual void operator()(int) {}
    virtual void operator()(bool) {}
    virtual void operator()(const std::string&) {}
};
```

Second, I define another visitor class that derives from the base one above:

```cpp
class CheckBooleanVisitor
    : public BaseVisitor {
public:
    CheckBooleanVisitor()
        : m_isBoolean(false) {
    }

    virtual void operator()(bool) override { // WHERE THE OVERRIDING TAKES PLACE
        m_isBoolean = true;
    }

    bool isBoolean() const {
        return m_isBoolean;
    }
};
```

I use this "derived" visitor class to visit a variant like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    Amalgamation a(0);
    Amalgamation b(false);
    CheckBooleanVisitor c;
    std::visit(c, a); // LINE #1
    std::cout << "a is " << (c.isBoolean() ? "" : "not ") << "a boolean." << std::endl;
    std::visit(c, b); // LINE #2
    std::cout << "b is " << (c.isBoolean() ? "" : "not ") << "a boolean." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the compiler (VS 2022) complains in `LINE #1` and `LINE #2` as follows:
`no instance of function template "std::visit" matches the argument list`

However, if I try:

```cpp
    std::visit((BaseVisitor&)c, a); // LINE #1
    std::visit((BaseVisitor&)c, b); // LINE #2
```

the program outputs as expected:

```
a is not a boolean.
b is a boolean.
```

Also, if I give `std::visit` an instance of `BaseVisitor`, no errors occur.

Why an object of the derived class `CheckBooleanVisitor` is not accepted as a valid callable for `std::visit` ?
P/s: I'm quite sure the cause of the problem is the code WHERE THE OVERRIDING TAKES PLACE in the definition of `CheckBooleanVisitor` above. But why ?

Comment: Broadly speaking, this code is a bad idea. Are you *sure* you need runtime polymorphism here? Do you have some function where the user has to pass in a runtime dynamic class that you will use to visit something? Wouldn't it be easier to just expose the variant and allow them to do the visitation?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I do allow the user to visit the variant. Freely. But inside the implementation, I want an elegant way to quickly check if the value of the variant is, say, a boolean, an integer, or an invalid string, etc. For each such specific purpose, I'd like to implement one visitor class, which should focus on only one overload of the `operator()`, while the other overloads should do nothing.

So I declare the base visitor class here, with all the useless (yet necessary for visitation) overloads, and let the specialized visitor classes derive from it and reimplement what they need.

Comment: `std::holds_alternative` can do what you're looking for.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you, definitely `std::holds_alternative` is what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function overloading (multiple functions of the same name in the same scope) and function overriding (a function in a derived class that provides a different implementation from a `virtual` base class version) interact in unpleasant ways.

If a base class defines a function with some name, and a derived class defines a function with that same name, the derived class will by default hide *all overloads* of the base class version. `operator()` is not an exception to this rule. Nor is the fact that the base class version is a `virtual` function that the derived class is `overriding`.

Therefore, if you want the non-overridden versions to be accessible through a derived class instance, you *must* explicitly `using` them:

```
    virtual void operator()(bool) override { // WHERE THE OVERRIDING TAKES PLACE
        m_isBoolean = true;
    }

    using BaseVisitor::operator();
```